# Support A4 PDF Output of My Resume

Tags: feature-request, jobs, pdf

Careers has a somewhat useful PDF Resume output.

It would be far more useful if I could print out my resume (eg. for reference while at an interview) without distortion.

Unfortunately the conversion function seems to be stuck in North America, having no option to change from letter sized pages to the A4 size everyone else uses.

Comment: Sounds like a browser issue, website can't control the selected page size.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The preview certainly, but on hitting "Export to PDF" a PDF file is downloaded from Careers: my browser does not create the PDF file. (If I were printing the preview this would be applicable.)

Comment: I just checked on a Windows machine using Adobe Reader X and it said 20.998 x 29.7cm which is so close (probably inches to metric conversion) I can't imagine it would be noticeable. What are you using to print it?

Comment: I'm using a Canon iP4500 set to A4. Without setting Foxit Reader to zoom down a little ("fit to printer margins") the sides are getting cut off as if I were printing Letter sized pages without zoom. Could this be a margin issue... the content is perhaps using close to 100% of the paper size not leaving room for the printer's minimum margins?

Answer (score 4):

The PDFs we create are already A4 size. Looking at the code, that's the option we explicitly set for the converter.

If I open mine using OS X's Preview, the inspector reports the size as "21 × 29.71 cm", which is A4.

Comment: See my latest comment to the Q. Also please note I have only ever seen this effect when printing content set of Letter size having forgotten to select to zoom to my printer's margins.

Comment: Not that I care, but once the A4 problems have been solved: don't the Northern America users want Letter next to A4?